# znapzend no longer works after upgrade to Ubuntu Server 20.04.1

Tags: zfs, znapzend

Ubuntu Server was upgraded from 18.04 LTS to 20.04.1 LTS and subsequently znapzend service fails to start with the reason being:
znapzend[3436]: ListUtil.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got handshake key 0xde00080, needed 0xcd00080)

I removed existing package and downloaded and installed the 0.20.0 deb package from https://github.com/Gregy/znapzend-debian/releases.  this did not fix the issue.

I understand that we are dealing with mismatch between different components built under different versions of perl libraries, but not being a perl coder I don't have a clue on how to proceed.

any suggestions?